# For $\rho$-varying function with $\rho>-1$, $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\int_0^t U(sx)ds }{\int_{N}^t U(sx)ds} = 1$

Tags: measure-theory

$U \colon (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ is called a $\rho$-varying function is $\frac{U(xt)}{U(t)} \to x^{\rho}$ as $t \to \infty$.

Here, we assume that $U$ is $\rho$-varying function with $\rho>-1$. Furthermore, we assume $U$ is locally integrable and that it's integrable on any interval of form $(0,b), b < \infty$.

In the proof I'm reading, we first prove that $\int_0^\infty U(t) dt = \infty$. Next, the proof says for $x>0$, $N<\infty$, $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\int_0^t U(sx)ds }{\int_{N}^t U(sx)ds} = 1$ as $U(sx)$ is $\rho$-varying function of $s$.

However, I do not understand why  $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\int_0^t U(sx)ds }{\int_{N}^t U(sx)ds} = 1$ holds. If someone could explain, I'd be grateful.

The proof is from  Extreme Values, Regular Variation and Point Processes by Resnick.

[image]

[image]

I had an attempt but I don't think it's the correct way as I don't believe I can apply L'Hopital rule like this:

Not sure if it's the right answer, but:

letting $F_1(t) = \int_0^t U(sx)ds$, $F_2(t) = \int_N^t U(sx)ds$ for $N<\infty$, as $U$ is locally integrable and integrable on any finite open interval containg $0$, we may simply apply L'Hôpital's rule to get

$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{F_1(t)}{F_2(t)} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{U(tx)}{U(tx)} = 1$.

This proof doesn't use that $U(sx)$ is $\rho$-varying, which is worrying.

Comment: I guess you could conclude that from the fact that the integral is infinite. The denominator and numerator differ only by a finite term, and both have infinite limits. The finite term effect tends to zero, hence the ratio tends to one.

Comment: @SBF, but $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ can be $\infty$ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that no one has addressed that yet. Define $G_x(s) := U(sx)$ then we're talking about
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_0^tG_x(s)\mathrm ds}{\int_N^tG_x(s)\mathrm ds} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_0^NG_x(s)\mathrm ds + \int_N^tG_x(s)\mathrm ds}{\int_N^tG_x(s)\mathrm ds} = 1+\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_0^NG_x(s)\mathrm ds }{\int_N^tG_x(s)\mathrm ds} = 1
$$
since the integral in the denomintar is infinite as $t\to 0$.

Comment: I wonder now, why do I have $t\to 0$ here...